# How to derive the solutions of a linear constant-coefficient differential equation

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

One thing I've hated about differential equations is how I need to *guess* the form of the solution.
e.g. it's easy to show that solutions to a linear constant-coefficient differential equation such as

$$y''' + 2 y'' + 3 y' + 4 y = 0$$

have the form of (some linear combination of) exponentials:
You can just plug in $y = e^{a x + b}$ and show that the equation is satisfiable.

But I feel there is something wrong if I *must* find the solutions through guess-and-check.
Yet what I was never told, and what I seem to never be able to find from looking online, is how to ***derive*** this fact rigorously, when I don't already have the intuition necessary to guess the form of the solution?

Sitting down and working through some math, I've come up with some *nonsense* that works quite beautifully:

1. Place the homogeneous equation into the following matrix form:
   $$\vec{y}\,' = A \vec{y}$$ where, for example, we have $\vec{y} = \begin{bmatrix} y & y' & \ldots \end{bmatrix}^T$
2. Drop the arrows and pretend everything is a scalar:
   $$y' = Ay$$
3. Separate the, uh, variables:
   $$\frac{dy}{dx} = A y$$
   $$\frac{dy}{y} = A\,dx$$
4. Integrate:
   $$\int \frac{dy}{y} = \int A\,dx$$

$$\ln y = A x + b$$

$$y = e^{A x + b}$$

5. Profit!

That was fun while it lasted... but how do I derive it *properly*?

Comment: I'm not sure this is any less rigorous than the same proof for a first-order equation, where the permissibility of separating variables is usually left unjustified...well, OK, here you definitely can't actually divide by $y$.

Comment: @KevinCarlson: It's way less rigorous. $dy/y$ is "vector division", for one thing... edit: yeah, you noticed it too.

Answer (score -1):

So, most of the math you've seen up to now is very simple, by mathematical standards.  The sorts of problems that come up in algebra, trig, and calculus courses can often be solved just by starting from an equation, applying a set of transformations to both sides of the equation, and arriving at an answer.

Most of math doesn't work that way *at all*.  I mean, consider Euclid's proof that there are infinitely many prime numbers, for instance.  Would you ask something like

"Why did I have to guess that looking at $p_1 p_2 \cdots p_n + 1$ and its factorization was the right thing to do?  Isn't there some way to just derive this automatically?"

No, of course not.  There's nothing nonrigorous about Euclid's proof, and there's nothing nonrigorous about observing that the $k$-th derivative of $e^{ax+b}$ is $a^k e^{ax+b}$, and that taking that together with the fundamental theorem of algebra will give us all the solutions we seek.

Comment: -1 because (1) Euclid's proof does *not* require guess and check, (2) I never said that the guess-and-check method is nonrigorous.

Comment: Sure it does.  It required him to "guess" that the correct number to look at was $p_1 p_2 \cdots p_n + 1$, in precisely the same sense that this requires you to "guess" that the solution is of the form $e^{ax +b}$.

Comment: No it does not. There is no guesswork involved there. It simply assumes that the claim is true and then proceeds by showing that he can construct another prime, which implies the claim is wrong -- all of which is very logical and requires zero guesswork. If you don't see the striking contrast between the two methods then I'm afraid you can't answer my question.

Comment: Perhaps you don't really understand the usual solution here.  Do you see why the solution to *any* linear differential equation $c_n y^{(n)} + c_{n-1} y^{(n-1)} + \cdots + c_1 y + c_0 = 0$ is always a linear combination of terms of the form $e^{ax + b}$?

Comment: In Euclid's proof, there is guesswork involved in the following sense.  He has a list of $n$ prime numbers, and wants to create a number which is divisible by none of them.  So he has to "guess" some function of $n$ numbers which will not be divisible by any of them, and then check that his function actually works.  Of course this is not how we usually think about this, but it's no different from "guessing" an ansatz to a differential equation and then proving that it works.

Comment: To answer your question: no, I *don't* see why, because your claim is false. And regarding your second comment: you're twisting the meaning of "guesswork" to fit the answer you want to give me. I know guesswork when I see it; I'm sure you do too. Euclid's proof does not involve guesswork, and I'm not going to play around with English here.

Comment: I understand that you believe there's a fundamental difference, because that's how I used to think before I'd seen a lot of math.  As you begin to read a lot more proofs, though, you'll eventually learn that most things don't pop out of equations, and that whether or not something is "guesswork" is more of a spectrum than something binary.

Comment: Incidentally, you *can* make this solution pop out of the equation if you want.  Just plug in an arbitrary Taylor series for $y$, derive the relevant recurrence relation for the coefficients and solve it, then note that your solution space has the proper dimension.  But it's vitally important that you understand that this method is no more rigorous than the one you've already seen.

Comment: *"But it's vitally important that you understand that this method is no more rigorous than the one you've already seen."* Er, I've said this once already in my first comment, and I'll say it again: *I **never said** that the guess-and-check method is nonrigorous.*

Comment: Also, I'm not saying math should *never* involve guess and check. I'm just asking for a solution to **this problem** that does not involve guesswork. I feel such a solution should be possible; either I'm right and your answer should provide such a solution, or I'm wrong and you can claim that "no such solution is possible/known/etc.". Your answer shouldn't start talking about the lack of a direct solution to entirely different problems. So, telling me that "most of math doesn't work that way" (a fact which I'm already aware of) is really *not* answering my question.